# Continuation of For Loop iteration

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, if-statement, finance

I iterate 250 times through a for loop, in this iteration an investment is invested into a risky asset and is performing.

If the value of the invested money reaches a certain treshold I need to stop the for loop, so that I can re-invest the money out of the risky asset into the riskless asset.

From there on I want the loop to continue with the amount of steps which are left (until 250) but this time the value needs to be multiplied with the riskfree rate.

My skript stops until the moment where the treshold is reached, can anyone help me out here how i can continue the iteration?

If you are looking for the Treshold part where the If clause is set--- > its in line 65 and line 84

```
%% market data & investor's preferences 
 % market
rF = 0.01; %Fixed return for riskfree asset
mu = 0.0031; %mean log return r- N(mu,sigma)
sigma = 0.19; %volatility
S0 = 100;  %initial price


%investor
V0 = 100; %amount to invest, initial wealth
T = 1; %investment horizon years
adjust_every = 1; %once every (for example 25 days if = 25) 50would be 5 times a year 
                  % try also 5, 63, 250

P = (0.05 * V0) + V0;          %critical value of profit  %take profit TP
Lc = V0 - (0.03 * V0);         %critical value of losses %stop losses SL




alpha = 1; %fraction of wealth in risky asset
dt = 1/250; %time increments.. we are interested in daily, weekly .... (1/250) should be daily for example
            % try also 1/50, 1/4 , 1
nExp = 1; %number of simulations

deltaAlphaCrit = 0.001; %try also for 0.001 0.005 , 0,01 , 0,02


%% simulate

%initialize variables for over time
M = round(T/dt) +1; %number of points in time to consider (we start at point 0)

rSim = randn(M,nExp) * sigma * sqrt(dt)+ mu * dt;
rSim(1,:) = 0;
S = S0 .* exp(cumsum(rSim)); 


for adjust_every =[1]

cash    = nan(M,nExp);
risky   = nan(M,nExp);
nStock  = nan(M,nExp);
wealth  = nan(M,nExp);

t = 1; %at the beginning of the investment horizon ...
cash(t,:)   = V0 * (1-alpha); %cash initially 
nStock(t,:) = (V0 * alpha) / S0;
risky(t,:) = nStock(t,:) .* S(t,:); % the risky asset is worth...
wealth(t,:) = cash(t,:) + risky(t,:);

% over time (what is happening)

for t = 1:(M-1)
    %at tb (begining of period t)
    tb = t;
    %transcost = 0,005 * S; %transaction costs
    if mod(tb-1, adjust_every) == 0 
        alphaCur = risky(tb,:) ./ wealth(tb,:); %current alpha , current fraction in risky asset
        nOpt = wealth(tb,:) * alpha ./ S(tb,:); %optimal number of risky assets you want to own 
        deltaN = nOpt - nStock(tb,:); % how many stocks to buy/sell ? if delta is pos-> buy , neg-> sell
    if risky(tb,:) > P
        nStock(tb,:) = nStock(tb,:);
        risky(tb,:) = risky(tb,:);
        cash(tb,:) = risky(tb,:)+exp(rF*dt);
        wealth(tb,:) = cash(tb,:);
        continue 
        %at te (end of period t)
        te = t+1;
        nStock(te,:)  = nStock(tb,:);
        risky(te,:)   = risky(tb,:);
        cash(te,:)    = cash(tb,:) * exp(rF*dt); %new cash postion %why exp ? -> log return
        wealth(te,:)  = cash(te,:);

        %results
        area([cash,risky])
        plot(wealth)
        VT = wealth(end,:);
        rT = VT./V0-1; %result of overall performance
        %break
    elseif risky(tb,:) < Lc
        nStock(tb,:) = nStock(tb,:);
        risky(tb,:) = risky(tb,:);
        cash(tb,:) = risky(tb,:)*exp(rF*dt);
        wealth(tb,:) = cash(tb,:);
        continue
        %at te (end of period t)
        te = t+1;
        nStock(te,:)  = nStock(tb,:);
        risky(te,:)   = risky(tb,:);
        cash(te,:)    = cash(tb,:) * exp(rF*dt); %new cash postion %why exp ? -> log return
        wealth(te,:)  = cash(te,:);

        %results
        area([cash,risky])
        plot(wealth)
        VT = wealth(end,:);
        rT = VT./V0-1; %result of overall performance
        %break
    else 
        nStock(tb,:) = nStock(tb,:);
        risky(tb,:) = nStock(tb,:) .* S(tb,:); %-transcost;
        cash(tb,:) = cash(tb,:) - deltaN.*S(tb,:); %-transcost;
        wealth(tb,:) = cash(tb,:) + risky(tb,:);
        %results
        area([cash,risky])
        plot(wealth)
        VT = wealth(end,:);
        rT = VT./V0-1; %result of overall performance
        %at te (end of period t)
        te = t+1;
        nStock(te,:)  = nStock(tb,:);
        risky(te,:)   = nStock(te,:) .* S(te,:);
        cash(te,:)    = cash(tb,:) * exp(rF*dt); %new cash postion %why exp ? -> log return
        wealth(te,:)  = cash(te,:) + risky(te,:);


    end 
        % changing postitions... what happened ?

       % nStock(tb,:) = nStock(tb,:) + deltaN;
       % risky(tb,:) = nStock(tb,:) .* S(tb,:); %-transcost;
       % cash(tb,:) = cash(tb,:) - deltaN.*S(tb,:); %-transcost;
       % wealth(tb,:) = cash(tb,:) + risky(tb,:);
    end 

    %at te (end of period t)
    %te = t+1;
    %nStock(te,:)  = nStock(tb,:);
    %risky(te,:)   = nStock(te,:) .* S(te,:);
    %cash(te,:)    = cash(tb,:) * exp(rF*dt); %new cash postion %why exp ? -> log return
    %wealth(te,:)  = cash(te,:) + risky(te,:);


end



%results
%area([cash,risky])
%plot(wealth)
%VT = wealth(end,:);
%rT = VT./V0-1; %result of overall performance

end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to stop the loop, you can just use an `if`-statement and a logical variables as some kind of flag:

```
FLAG_REINVEST = false;
for i = 1:250 % loop through 250 iterations

    if value > Threshold
        % risk-free case
        if FLAG_REINVEST
            % do reinvestment
            FLAG_REINVEST = false; % set flag
        end
        % do the other stuff in the risk-free case
    else
        % risky asset
    end
end
```

Comment: can you use my code to implement that ? 

For me it does not work, after the Treshold is reached and you should take the money to invest in the risk-free case, there are NaN

Comment: Sorry, your code is long and clumsy, I won't do free coding for you but I will help you to learn it yourself. If you break up your code into functions (e.g. a `investMoney`-function) it will be easier to put it in the structure I proposed =)

Answer (score -1):

use two while loops:

```matlab
t = 1;
while t < M-1
    t=t+1
    //invest

    if ... break
end

if t < M-1
    //re-invest
    ...
end

while t < M-1
    t=t+1
    //riskfree stuff
    ....
end
```

Comment: hey! Thank you for the quick answer....

Im kinda new to programming, could you show me how you would implement that ?

Comment: just copy-paste your code into the structure above: in the first while-loop, you put the invest-section. into the second loop, you put the risk-free stuff which will continue your iterations as you asked since t has not changed

Comment: it says invalid operator for the (t++ < M-1) part

Comment: and if i change t++ into t+1 MATLAB is going to crash

Comment: This is not valid MATLAB syntax.

Comment: you know the valid syntax in MATLAB for that issue?

Comment: sorry for that, my matlab days were 20 years ago.